# javascript load php on div doesn't work with Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have several php pages that create dynamically links with javascript scripts which load different content in the same div. The function that creates the links is the following:

```
$variablephp = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT `BASIC` FROM `roleflow_training` WHERE `ROLE_ID`=".$variablephp.""); //Once the text has been saved in the BBDD: 
$result = mysql_result ($result, 0, "BASIC");
$result = preg_replace("/\n+/", "\n",$result); 
$lineas = explode("\n", $result); 
echo "<ul>\n"; 

foreach ($lineas as $bullet) 
{ 
    $test = preg_replace("/\n+/", "", $bullet);
    $prueba = chop($test, "\n");
    $prueba = chop($prueba, "\b");
    $prueba = chop($prueba, "\br");
    $prueba = "'".$prueba."'";
    $link = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cursos_training` WHERE `COURSE_NAME`=".$prueba."");
    $existe = mysql_num_rows($link);
    if ($existe < 1)
    {
        echo "<li>".$test."</li>\n"; 
    }
    else
    {
        $fila = mysql_fetch_array($link);
        $enlace = $fila['IDLINK'];
        $direccion = "<a href=\"javascript:$('#floatFlowCursos').css('display','none');$('#contentFlow').load('curso1_info.php?id=".$enlace."')\">";
        echo "<li>".$direccion.$bullet."</a>"."</li>\n"; 
    }
} 
echo "</ul>";
```

This sentence works perfectly with Chrome but not with Firefox or I Explorer, do you have any idea?

Thank you so much for your support!! Cheers!!

Comment: Any messages in the console? It sounds like a javascript syntax error somewhere.

Comment: For your information don't use load it is deprecated from jQuery after 1.7

Comment: I guess you're talking about a different load function. What you're talking about is the `load-event` method that binds a `load` event to an element. http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: please check out the question again friends!

Comment: can you show the rendered html?

Comment: var ul = document.getElementById("ULfloatFlowCursos");
ul.innerHTML = "";
ul.innerHTML += " <a href=\"javascript:\$('#contentFlow').load('curso1_info.php?id=12001;');\$( '#floatFlowCursos' ).slideUp( 'slow', function(){});\" class=\"course12\" id=\"course12\" style=\"color:#FFF; font-size:25px; text-decoration:none; margin-bottom:40px;\">1 - AB Course<br><br></a>";